# SpringBoot 2 Migration from 1.5 Dependencies Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am working to migrate from Springboot 1.5 to 2.1.  Our project has a main build.gradle file and then four subprojects (acceptance, application, shared, integration) with build.gradle it in.  The problem is that the "shared" subproject is dependent on models from the "application" subproject and no longer seems to be able to pick them up.  In IntelliJ I can tell it to import the models and it accepts that but when I do a "gradle clean build" it **fails** for the following:

```
C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-customer\shared\src\test\java\com\##MASKED##\brokerage\customer\util\OrgTrustUtil.java:563: error: cannot find symbol
    public static BrokerageCustomer generateExpectedBrokerageCustomer() {
                  ^
  symbol:   class BrokerageCustomer
  location: class OrgTrustUtil
```

I am new to using gradle (used maven in the past).  The build.gradle file for shared is:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
//    testCompile project(':application').sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Note that I have commented out the testCompile line as it was fine in 1.5 but errors in 2.1.

I am kind of assuming the issue is with the testCompile having to be commented out but I have not found how to keep it since it errors when I try to build.

I found the issue was that I had not applied the dependency manager plugin.  Adding this made it work:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    testCompile project(':application').sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was that I had not applied the dependency manager plugin.  Adding this made it work:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    testCompile project(':application').sourceSets.main.output
}
```